# What did the man say? (From Köln Karneval)

Tags: listening-comprehension

[This](https://youtu.be/T_TQQu6hQFs) 10-second video is a clip my English son in law sent us today from Köln.  Though I'm learning German myself, I cannot  understand what the speaker said.
To me, it sounds like (even after getting help from youtube's automatic translation, it doens't still make sense..),

> Er kommt. Ich darf unseren Messdiener wütend(?), bereits schon.
> Übergebe das Mikrofon gerne an Monsignore Rhoback(?).

I'm curious. What did the German man say?

Comment: @CarstenS Sorry, I added the link.

Comment: Youtube's automatic subtitle function is surprisingly good here and might already help you a lot (But still not perfect)

Comment: @tofro Yes, I didn't check the automatic caption after the youtube upload. Because the clip starts and ends in the middle of a statement, the automatic interpretation couldn't catch it all exactly, but sure it helps me alot. and I realize I could use this method in this situation. But the interpretation is unnatural in a couple of places as you said.

Comment: At the end of the video I hear "Monsignore Robert K"[end of recording] and strongly suspect he means [Stadtdechant](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekan_(Kirche)) [Monsignore Robert Kleine](https://www.ksta.de/koeln/karneval-in-koeln/segen-fuer-die-session-karnevalsgottesdienst-im-koelner-dom-386673?cb=1673106187878), who was involved in the celebrations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Er kommt – und ich darf unseren Messdiener bitten, parat zu stonn (= bereit zu stehen), und übergebe das Mikrofon gerne an Monsignore Robert ...

Comment: Ah, thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, @DonHolgo, is 'parat zu stonn' a dialect? or is it just a mis-prunciation?

Comment: I think "parat" is used in other regions too (it even has a Wiktionary entry), "stonn" is the dialect version of "stehen".

Comment: There is also a [well known Karneval song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJpTDLVx6aQ) that includes "dann stonn mer all parat" (dann stehen wir alle bereit) in its refrain, so even people who don't usually speak Kölsch may use this phrase during Karneval.